# Background in an iPhone Quartz CAAnimation

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

Whenever I am using a quartz animation the background of the animation is white. How can I change this to be a different color. This is the code I am using to produce the animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:superview cache:YES];
[superview addSubview:backview];
[defaultview removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: By background, do you mean the underside of the curled view?

Comment: I actually meant the background when I use a FlipFromLeft, I corrected this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the background color for these transitions is the same as the background color of your app's one `UIWindow` object - its main window.

You can set this color in the nib file, usually called `MainWindow.xib`, using interface builder.

You can also set this programmatically, such as in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method of your app delegate object, via something like this:

```
UIColor* myColor = [UIColor blackColor];  // Or any other color you want.
[window setBackgroundColor:myColor];
```

By the way, you can also set this "color" to be an image using a method such as [`colorWithPatternImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithPatternImage:), one of the convenience constructors of `UIColor`.

Reference: [a previous question on the flipping views background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079011/iphone-flipping-views-shows-a-white-background/1079811).

Answer (score 0):

By background means animation or whole view background?