# How to change shadow background white to other colors

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to change `UIPageViewController` shadow color while doing a flip animation.
But always it displaying white color only.
How to change a color of flip side background color white to other colour like (black or sephia). iBook is doing same thing.

I mention that below image have white bg that color i would to change.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please find the attachment of my screen shot
http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/xo7tttfxq3s6fdhk60s.png

Comment: check out this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079011/iphone-flipping-views-shows-a-white-background

Comment: @Ganee hope u seen image attachment.
http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/xo7tttfxq3s6fdhk60s.png

I am using UIPageViewController so animation is already there.
I need to modify back color as i mention in my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:index];
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(imageRect,
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, [image CGImage]);
}
```

Comment: What will do aspectFit(imageRect,
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx)); method

Answer (score 10):

I've been trying to do the same thing for some time now and I finally figured it out. Turns out you can't set the background color to other colors, but you can provide another view that UIPageViewController will add to the back. And that's the secret here.

From Apple's documentation:

```
Spine location                                Double sided               What to pass
UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid               YES               Left and Right Page.
SpineLocationMin or SpineLocationMax               YES               Front and Back of the page.
SpineLocationMin or SpineLocationMax               NO                Front page only.
```

So, basically, you need to set double sided property to yes and provide two viewControllers on both Data Source methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Each method will be called twice for every new page you add. So, you need to provide the viewController you would normally return and also a new viewController that will be added to the back when doing the page turning animation.

It's up to you what your "BackViewController" will have. You can simply have a black view or if you want, you can take a screenshot of the front page, and get a mirrored image from it.

It's not hard once you understand how it works. The only problem I can see here is that when you add a black view or anything that has a black background, the shadow when turning the page becomes WHITE. I have no idea why, but I've seen this happening on a lot of different apps, so I guess to Apple this is the normal behavior. But it looks really weird.

**EDIT:**

I've added a sample code so it is easier to understand.
https://github.com/mattabras/DoubleSidedPageViewController

Abras

Comment: Could you please post some code - I get the theory, but can't see how it works in practise. I've only got one 'page' - a double sided page...

Comment: @Abras- Would it be possible for you to elaborate or maybe post an example please? I've tried to implement what you said to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: You can get a sample code here. https://github.com/mattabras/DoubleSidedPageViewController

Comment: I don't understand. If you found the code useful at least give the guy some votes! Think.

Comment: With iOS 13 and Dark Mode, I found the default color, white, to be jarring when in dark mode. I consider it a bug.  This is the only solution I was able to find and should probably be the accepted answer.  My app hangs when snapshotting the view like the repo shows, but I was able to just add some state to my vcs (isBackside) and use the same logic of conditionally injecting "mirror" vcs in the data source.  This seems like a lot of work for this feature though, would be nice to have a `var backsideColor: UIColor` exposed in the sdk.

Answer (score -2):

In the case of pagecontrol selectable page visibility color--

UIPageControl does not support this by default. You have to create your own page control and do the drawing on your own.

Comment: I'm using UIPageViewController not UIPageControl. UIPageViewController I'm developing application like iBook, while doing page curl animation  behind white shadow is there by default. I need to change that bg colour.

Comment: Sample image link . while doing page curl that white bg is there my application is supporting night mode so i need to change black colour.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image:Iphone_ios_5_uipageviewcontroller_app.jpg