# UIPageViewController backside view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a working UIPageviewcontroller in my app.
I want to customize the backside of the page that is shown when a user is turning the page. 
The default behaviour right now is showing the frontview at 40% or so.
Is it possible to set it up in a way that the backside is a view I specify?

EDIT:
maybe I should clarify that I want the backside of the view to always be the same view. for example a solid red color. same question has been asked here [How to change shadow background white to other colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381773/uipageviewcontroller-how-to-change-shadow-background-white-to-other-colors-i)

this is the code I use in the spine position method. in the comments of the setViewControllers method I read:

`For transition style 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl', if 'doubleSided' is 'YES' and the spine location is not 'UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid', two view controllers must be included, as the latter view controller is used as the back.`

so if I do:

```
-(UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation    (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    UIViewController *currentViewController = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
    UIViewController *backsideViewController = [[BackSideViewController alloc]init];
    self.pageViewController.doubleSided = YES;
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[currentViewController,backsideViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers     direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:NULL];
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax;
}
```

I get the error:

`The number of provided view controllers (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax)`