# Change the back-side color for UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

When I using `UIPageViewController`, the back-side color of the page is always white. How can I change the color ?

Comment: check out this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079011/iphone-flipping-views-shows-a-white-background

Comment: I want to achieve the same (actually displaying an own Page without the mirroring of the last page. Unfortunately using doubleSided = YES and providing a special view controller for the back side seems not to work together with UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin. The docs say "Pass the front of the page to be displayed and the back of the previously-displayed page. The back is used for the page turning animation.", but this does not seem to work for me...

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the window background color. You should set the window background color:

`appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Comment: Absolutely wrong. Your suggestion doesn't work. I use UIPageViewController embedded in the other view and I can definitely say that the scroll view of Page Controller is white and opaque.